# Electron with nightmare

Tags: webpack, electron, nightmare, asar

I am trying to create an Electron.js app using Nightmare headless browser. I do not use IPC. My Electron config is:

```
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

When I try to import Nightmare module, I got an error:

`Cannot find module '/.../node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/package.json'`

This error seems to be webpack related. Any idea? Thanks!